# How to filter record "sequences" from a Polars dataframe using multiple threads?

Tags: python-polars

I have a data set with multiple records on each individual - one record for each time period.
Where an individual is missing a record for a time period, I need to remove any later records for that individual.
So given an example dataset like this:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'Id': [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6],
 'Age': [1,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,4,2,3,4],
 'Value': [1,142,4,73,109,145,6,72,-8,67,102,-1,72,150,72,111,149]})
df
```

```
Id  Age Value
i64 i64 i64
1   1   1
1   4   142
2   1   4
2   2   73
2   3   109
2   4   145
3   1   6
3   2   72
4   1   -8
4   2   67
4   3   102
5   1   -1
5   2   72
5   4   150
6   2   72
6   3   111
6   4   149
```

I need to filter it as follows:

```
Id  Age Value   Keep
i64 i64 i64 bool
1   1   1   true
2   1   4   true
2   2   73  true
2   3   109 true
2   4   145 true
3   1   6   true
3   2   72  true
4   1   -8  true
4   2   67  true
4   3   102 true
5   1   -1  true
5   2   72  true
```

So an individual with an age record profile of `1,3,4` would end up with only the `1` record. An individual like Id 6 with an age record profile of `2,3,4` would end up with no records after filtering.

I can achieve this using the approach below, however when the data set contains millions of individuals, the code appears not to run in parallel and performance is very slow (The steps prior to the final `filter` expression complete in ~22 seconds on a data set with 16.5 million records, the last `filter` expression takes another 12.5 *minutes* to complete). Is there an alternative approach that will not be single-threaded, or an adjustment of the code below to achieve that?

```py
df2 = (
    df.sort(by=["Id","Age"])
    .with_column(
        ((pl.col("Age").diff(1).fill_null(pl.col("Age") == 1) == 1)
        .over("Id")
        .alias("Keep")
    )
    .filter(
        (pl.col("Keep").cumprod() == 1).over("Id")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose the following (revised) code:

```py
df2 = df.filter(pl.col('Age').rank().over('Id') == pl.col('Age'))
```

This code yields the following result on your test dataset:

```
shape: (12, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ Id  ┆ Age ┆ Value │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 73    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 109   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 145   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 6     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 72    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 1   ┆ -8    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 2   ┆ 67    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 102   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 1   ┆ -1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 2   ┆ 72    │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

Basically, when an `Age` is skipped (for a particular `Id`), the `rank` of the `Age` falls out of step with the `Age` variable itself, and remains out of step for all higher `Age` values for that `Id`.

This code has several advantages over my prior answer.  It is more concise, it's far easier to follow, and best of all ... it makes excellent use of the Polars API, particularly the `over` window function.

Even if this code benchmarks slightly slower in the upcoming Polars release, I recommend it for the reasons above.

## Edit - Benchmarks on Polars 0.13.15

ok, wow wow wow ... I just downloaded the newly released Polars (0.13.15), and re-benchmarked the code on my machine with the 17 million records generated as in my prior answer.

The results?

- The revised code listed in the question: 13.6 seconds
- The (ugly) code in my prior answer: 4.8 seconds
- The one-line code in this answer: 3.3 seconds

And from watching the `htop` command while the code runs, it's clear that the newly released Polars code utilized all 64 logical cores on my machine.  *Massively parallel*.

Impressive!

Comment: @tikkanz can you accept this as the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice clean solution to the problem. I can confirm it executes about twice as fast as the revised code in the question on the real data. The changes in 0.13.15 make that code run in less than a minute on a 4 core machine with 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `window` functions are very powerful, but also relatively expensive. So you could already start by doing less work.

```py
df.sort(by=["Id", "Age"]).filter(
    ((pl.col("Age").diff(1).fill_null(1) == 1).over("Id"))
)
```

And very likely, you can also ditch the expensive sort:

```py
df.filter(
    ((pl.col("Age").diff(1).fill_null(1) == 1).over("Id"))
)
```

### Multithreading

The `filter` operation already consists of many forms of parallelism. The materialization of the columns is parallel. And in this case the computation of the mask is parallel as well. A `window` expression (`over()` syntax), is multithreaded in computing the groups as well as doing the join operation.

### Squeezing out maximum performance of a window function

If your data is already sorted you can make a `window` expression often faster by explicitly adding a `list` aggregation and then flattening that result. This is because the list aggregation is free, as we already have a list in aggregation (implementation detail) and the flatten is often also free. A bit of a complicated implementation detail, but it means that polars doesn't have to compute the location of every aggregation relative to the original `DataFrame`.

**This only makes sense if the DataFrame is already sorted by the groups**.

```py
# note that that only makes sense if the df is sorted by the groups
sorted_df.filter(
    ((pl.col("Age").diff(1).fill_null(1) == 1).list().over("Id").flatten())
)
```

Comment: The diff function is a nice simplification! The code provided achieve the desired result (e.g. Id 6 should be dropped) - is it intended to be part of, rather that the full solution?

Comment: It is intended as the full solution. I understood it as that you only want to select subsequent values incremented by 1.

Comment: Hopefully the following examples of filtering for Individuals with various age record profiles will help `1,3,4` -> `1` ; `2,3,4` -> `No records`

Comment: I have updated the code in the question with some of the suggested improvements. On a dataset of ~16.5 million records it takes about 22seconds to complete everything except the last filter expression. Including that step, the code completes in ~13 minutes. Is that performance expected?